# I am developing simple Rest service which will return simple "Hello", but i am unable to run that on tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, spring-boot

I created the Spring boot project using spring boot initial then unzipped that imported in eclipse,while running it. it is perfectly running.
but while developing simple hello rest service. getting 404 not found

Tried removing the tomcat server and configuring it again
server is running fine on same server.

This is my Rest Controller class

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController; 

//Controller 
@RestController 
public class HelloWorldController { 
  //Method- HelloRest!! 
  //URI- /hello-rest 
  //GET- request 
  //@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,path="/hello-rest") 
  @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world") 
  public String helloWorld() { 
     return "Hello World!!"; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Please share your error, code that can help us in identifying your issue. Welcome to community.

Comment: Your Rest Controller class is missing

Comment: Here is my restContoller class-
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

//Controller
@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {
 
 //Method- HelloRest!!
 //URI- /hello-rest
 //GET- request
 //@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,path="/hello-rest")
 @GetMapping(path = "/hello-world")
 public String helloWorld()
 {
  return "Hello World!!";
 }
}

Comment: Please make sure that your hello-world controller, should be in the same package level or in sub package level of your starter/main class (i.e @SpringBootApplication)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i have done and it's working with tomcat and JBoss.
http://localhost:8085/test/testCall - this is the URL i am hitting for following code in postman.
Can you share your URL you are trying to hit

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class ServiceController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/testCall", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String  testCall(){
        return "Service Up!!!";
    }
}
```